# UDP load balancer using Netty

Tags: java, multithreading, udp, netty

I'm writing a `UDP` load balancer using `Netty`.

The load balancer listens on a local transport address. In terms of `Netty`, only one `Channel` is created in order to listen on this address. Incoming UDP packets are then dispatched by the single thread (of the single-threaded event loop group) to a pool of worker threads for processing (here, processing means performing load balancing).

On the outbound side, multiple servers are available. For every received UDP packet, the associated worker thread selects a server and forwards the UDP packet to this server. In order to forward the UDP packet, a `Channel` is needed.

I can see four approaches:

1. Using a single outbound `Channel` that is used to forward all packets to servers. Using this approach, the packets will always be sent from the same transport address.
2. Using one outbound `Channel` per available server. Every packet forwarded to a server will be forwarded using the `Channel` associated with that server.
3. Using **N** outbound `Channel` per available server. Every packet forwarded to a server will be forwarded using a `Channel` from the group of `Channels` associated with that server.
4. Using a new `Channel` for every packet to forward.

I tried approach 4 and I can see it yields bad performance. Especially, I had an issue where too many sockets were created and therefore it exceeded the open files limit.

Because `Channels` are shared between multiple packets, approaches 1, 2 and 3 require adding the request's sender address inside the UDP packet, but that's not an issue for me since I need this information for the server that will actually processes the packet.

What is the recommended approach between 1, 2 and 3? Is it good practice to use one or more `Channel` per destination server?

---

**EDIT** :

Another approach that comes to my mind is to use a shared pool of `Channels`. When a UDP packet is received, an available server is selected, then a `Channel` is selected from the pool (e.g. using round robin selection algorithm) and the packet is forwarded using this `Channel`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with you and I use the `Another approach`. But I didn't select `Another approach` for performance issue of the balancer,  but for performance issue of the available servers.

For the balancer's performance, I don't notice much difference between approach 1 and `Another approach` for my performance test. And Netty has upper limit rate of one listen channel, I think you'd better use `EpollChannelOption.SO_REUSEPORT` to create multiple listen channels.